# Bypassing cloudfront caching

Tags: http, caching, https, amazon-cloudfront, cache-control

I want to bypass the cloudfront cache of a API, but everything I have tried has failed.

I use several proxies to send a request to an API, but because of the Cloudfront cache it takes almost 2 minutes to get the updated data.

I tried to add "Cache-Control": "no-cache", "pragma": "no-cache" header but the server ignored it.
I tried to add a random query but this time I got HTTP ERROR 400, the API doesn't allow me to add a random query.

So how can I bypass the cache, do you have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable CloudFront's caching by adding the [Managed-CachingDisabled](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudFront/latest/DeveloperGuide/using-managed-cache-policies.html#managed-cache-policy-caching-disabled) cache policy to the CloudFront cache behavior for the origin serving your API.